# Not able to find out g++

Tags: g++

I have installed g++ in Ubuntu 12.04 from Ubuntu software center to write, c and c++  and to complie, but I am not able to find out where is the software gone after installation, please help me how to find it.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? What happens if you open a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) and type `which g++` or `g++ --version`?

Comment: g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: Yes that error comes

Comment: That isn't really an error. You have started `g++` without a source-code file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start:

```
dpkg -L g++
```

to list all installed files for the package `g++` or use:

```
which g++
```

to show the path for the command `g++`

---

Write a "hello world"

1. Open a sour-code file

   ```
   nano helloworld.cpp
   ```
2. Add the code below

   ```
   #include <iostream>                                     
   int main(){                                             
       std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
       return 0;                                           
   }
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Compile

   ```
   g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
   ```
5. Start

   ```
   ./helloworld
   ```

Comment: dpkg -L g++
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/doc
/usr/bin/i686-linux-gnu-g++
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/share/man/man1/i686-linux-gnu-g++.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/g++

Comment: Yes that error comes

Comment: @LaBelleNoiseuse Which error?